# how to get data from linq database model

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am trying use LINQ in a C# program to get information from a database. I have found a lot of examples showing basic to advanced queries, but i get a error when i try to build. See basic LINQ example below:
The class with the LINQ

```
 public class StdFy
{
    public object GetStdFy(DrillholeEntities ddb)
    {
        try
        {
            var myList = ((from t1 in ddb.DTM_QAQC_BLK_STD from t2  in ddb.DTM_STANDARDSASSAY.Where(x=> t1.STANDARDID==x.STANDARDID && t1.ASSAYVALUE==x.STANDARDVALUE)
                           select new
                           {
                               CHECKID = t1.CHECKID,
                               STANDARDID = t1.STANDARDID,
                               PRIORITY = t1.ASSAY_PRIORITY,
                               NAME = t1.ASSAYNAME,
                               ASSAYVALUE = t1.ASSAYVALUE,
                               STANDARDVALUE = t2.STANDARDVALUE,
                               STANDARDDEVIATION = t2.STANDARDDEVIATION,
                               NORMALIZACION = (t2.STANDARDVALUE- t1.ASSAYVALUE)/ t2.STANDARDDEVIATION,
                               LABJOBNO = t1.LABJOBNO,
                               LOADDATE = t1.RETURNDATE


                           })).OrderBy(x => x.LOADDATE).ToList();

            return myList;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {              
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
DrillholeEntities ddb;
StdFy stdFy = new StdFy();
using (ddb = new DrillholeEntities())
                {

                    IOrderedEnumerable<DTM_QAQC_BLK_STD> datosTodos;
                    datosTodos = stdFy.GetStdFy(ddb);
                 }
```

and when i buuild the project i get the error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to
>   'System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)    Inspinia_MVC5   C:\Users\chachl9\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\MVC5_Full_Version\Inspinia_MVC5\Controllers\GraphsController.cs 55  Active

Comment: The type you return from query is anonymous - and it can't be cast to `DTM_QAQC_BLK_STD`. You need to alter your query: `select new DTM_QAQC_BLK_STD {...}`.

Comment: but i have 2 tables in my query , what i have to do ia get a error when a alter using just DTM_QAQC_BLK_STD

Comment: You need DTM_QAQC_BLK_STD - so `select` it!

Comment: Also, do yourself a big favor and use PascalCased property- and class names. You're using an object-relational *mapper*, i.e. the names in the class model are mapped to (and thus independent of) the database object names.

Comment: The error message says what to do. `datosTodos = (IOrderedEnumerable<DTM_QAQC_BLK_STD>)stdFy.GetStdFy(ddb);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a list of objects of an anonymous type by

```
select new { ... }
```

thats may the reason why you use object as return type of your method.
Than you assign the return value to a specific type. Thats the reason why the exception ist thrown.

To get this work I would implement a new class  which contains all your needed properties. Use it in

```
select new MyNewClass { Property1 = ...}
```

change the return type of your method from object to `IEnumerable<MyNewClass>`. Aswell the variable you assign the return value to.

---

You should also use PascalCase properties as mentioned by Gert Arnold in the comments.

Also mixing the `select from in where` LINQ syntax with the Lambda methods `.Where(x => ...)` make it hard to read.